# How to use JQuery to detect value-changed event when user drag & drop text into textbox?

Tags: jquery, input, drag-and-drop

I'm using this jQuery code

```
$('input').bind('change mouseup', ... )
```

to detect if user drag text somewhere into my input & change it value. But that seems doesn't work. Why doesn't it work and how I can get it to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var inputField = $("input");
var oldValue = inputField.text();
inputField.bind("drop", function() {
    //when the drop happens the input value will not be updated yet
    //use a timeout to allow the input value to change.
    setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        if (this.value !== oldValue) {
            $(this).trigger('change');
        }
    }, this), 0);
});
$("input").bind("change", function() {
    oldValue = this.value;
});
```

run the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/paulwesterberg/FJuvz/5/

Comment: Thanks ! Your code worked well, but if you can make the change-event trigger right after the left-mouse is released (mouse up event), it should be perfect.

Comment: Btw this code works fine for firefox & IE, but does not work for chrome(webkit?) which handles the drop event differently. I tried a couple of workarounds but haven't found a solution.

Comment: OK, I found a work around for chome, add "drop" code above to the focus event also. Chrome will transfer focus as part of the drop and the input value will be updated after the focus event fires.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery 1.10.1 - I had success with this...

```
$('body').on('input paste drop', '#txt-some-id, function() {
    $('#btn-some-id').prop("disabled", $(this).val().length === 0);
});
```

Comment: You only need to use the `input` event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `paste` event with little amount of timeout until the value is pasted if you want to use it or fire a change event. Try this

```
$("input").bind('paste', function(e) {
        var $el = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            //Here you can use the pasted value or trigger the text change event
            $el.trigger('change');
        }, 100);
});
```

Comment: sorry but your code didn't work at all. Btw, you cannot use the setTimeout function with the 1st param as a function instead of a string. -1 point for that mistake.