# Firefox loads as an url the dropped text in input field

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop

In Firefox only, if I highlight text and drop it into the *middle* of an existing textfield I get an error message:

> The URL is invalid and cannot be loaded.

I created a sample here http://jsfiddle.net/XtGdd/2/

Highlight the `drag me` text. Then click and drag it into the text of the input box.
- If I drop it after the input text, it will run fine.
- If I drop it inside the input text I get the error.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to work around it?

What I am trying to do is to replace the value of the textfield by the one dropped. In this case, to clear the field and replace with the dropped text.

Comment: +1 Weird problem. I hope someone finds an answer for you.

Comment: What is the end use case? Drop text in, then what? Clear field and replace with dropped text? Not sure if you will find a solution, so I am trying to think of some workarounds.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be broken in Chrome for you too. In Chrome nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Here - this SO question may solve your problem cross-browser. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265119/how-to-use-jquery-to-detect-value-changed-event-when-user-drag-drop-text-into

Comment: Thank you, I tried to add a line to clear the field but the same error occured. I am looking for a way to catch the hovering event while dragging my highlighted text.

Comment: When you find a solution to your own question you should actually submit an answer. Then accept it. Glad you found an answer and it always amazes me when something so 'trivial' is such a hard thing to fix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution I put in http://jsfiddle.net/XtGdd/12/ thanks from this [question](http://goo.gl/xdZPM)

```
$('#text_input_')
    .bind("dragover", false)    #=> for Chrome to catch the drop event;
    .bind("dragenter", false)   #=> for Chrome to catch the drop event;
    .bind('drop', function(e){  #=> Cancel the drop and just set the value directly;
        $('#text_input_').val(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));
        return false;
});
```

I don't really feel safe with it but at the moment, that is the only thing I found.

Comment: Preventing default `drop` action - it's exactly what I need to block loading of dropped text as URL!