# Detect drop event

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on a project. There are two buttons which are bound to two divs. When button 1 is pushed #draggableDiv 1 is shown and if button 2 is pushed #draggableDiv2 is shown. They can then be dragged to #droppableDiv. I want to be able to recognize which div has been dropped.

```
if("#draggableDiv1" == dropped)
    {
      Run this code;
}else{
      Run this code;
```

Comment: pd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265119/how-to-use-jquery-to-detect-value-changed-event-when-user-drag-drop-text-into

Comment: You forgot to mention or u use jQuery UI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you in your droppable options you pass the event and ui arguments like this:

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
```

Then in your drop function you can detect it like this:

```
var dropped = ui.draggable.attr('id');
if ("draggableDiv1" == dropped)
etc.
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code helped though I did not use it exactly as you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to take a look at jQuery UI Draggrable

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ and specifically on http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart